# Initializing a cubemap with existing 2D textures and glTextureView

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I am trying to create a cubemap from six existing textures. Texture views seem to be made for this sort of thing, also updating the cubemap when the original textures change. However, cubemaps can only be views of texture arrays (or other cubemaps) and i can't find any way to fill an array with several already existing 2D textures using `glTextureView` since `glTextureView` can only be used with uninitialized textures.

Is there a way to do this or is drawing into the cubemap via an FBO the only way?

Comment: See, there maybe a way, but as the question is currently written, it's less likely to receive an answer. Can you please elaborate it?

Comment: Also, if it helps, see [Ask] and take a [tour].

Comment: Thanks for the edit, english not being my strong point it really helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I do not believe this is supported. You can't "merge" multiple textures into a single texture without any copying.

I can think of a few options you have:

- The ideal solution is of course that you place the data into cube map faces in the first place, instead of using separate textures. Note that `gTextureView()` supports the opposite direction. If you partly want to use a texture as a regular `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, and partly as the face of a cube map, you can store it in a cube map face, and create a texture view to treat the face as a 2D texture where that's needed.
- You copy the textures into the cube map faces. The most efficient approach should be using `glBlitFramebuffer()`. Of course copying data is always undesirable, but sometimes it's necessary.
- This may be somewhat unconventional, but you could... not use a cube map. You could use 6 separate samplers in the shader, and bind the 6 textures you want to use as cube faces to those samplers. Then you can decide which of the six textures to sample, and what texture coordinates to use, in your shader code. This shouldn't be too difficult if you look up the logic/math that is used under the hood when you sample cube maps.